# What is the value of these phantom shares?

Tags: contract-law

The wording of this paragraph is not clear to me. Does the value of the Phantom Units equate to 0.25% of the FMV or do they equate to 0.25% of 10% of full FMV?

> The number of Phantom Units granted hereby is intended to equate to
>   one-quarter of one percent (0.25%) of the Fair Market Value of the
>   Company as if the maximum number of Phantom Units that may be awarded
>   under the Plan are outstanding, inclusive of the Phantom Units granted
>   hereby, which in the aggregate represent 10% of the Fair Market Value
>   of the Company, and the remaining 90% of the Fair Market Value of the
>   Company is represented by the outstanding Class A Units held by the
>   Founder Group.

For example: Assuming the contract awards 100 Phantom Units and the company is valued at $10M which of the following two calculations correctly interprets the value of the Phantom Units?

A) 0.25% of 10% of $10M = $2,500

or

B) 0.25% of 100% of $10M = $25,000

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is this not just a math question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Law as defined in the help center.

Comment: This is not a math question. It's the "legalize" that I'm having a hard time parsing.

Comment: It's not clear to me if the 0.25% applies to the full FMV or just 10% of the full market value.

Answer (score 1):

You can value all of the phantom stock in that particular grant (i.e. $25,000 which is 0.25% of the $10,000,000 FMV of the Company), or you can value the total amount of phantom stock which can be issued (i.e. $1,000,000 which is 10% of the $10,000,000 FMV).

But, you cannot value 100 shares of phantom stock because the information provided doesn't state how many shares of phantom stock are bring granted.

Your question indicates that your understanding of the language you are reading is flawed. This is simply a matter of carefully reading the words that you are quoting.

Comment: Exactly. The language is not clear to me. I proved two example calculations based on two interpretations of the language. The contract does, in fact, award shares (t's just not 100). 100 an example number of shares with which to evaluate wording.

Comment: @Tedsterr Do you understand that the per share value is the total value of the shares granted (i.e. $25,000) divided by the (unknown) number of shares granted?

Comment: I guess that is exactly my question. The answer is "A" (if for example, the number of Phantom Units granted were 100).